# Filling down a VLOOKUP formula without changing the range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I am comparing values in a row in one sheet to values in another row in another sheet.  The following formula and works:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A1:A19240,1,FALSE),"No Match")
```

My problem is when I fill down the formula, it increments A1 correctly but also increments the `(A1:A19240)`, so half way down I have narrowed the search field.

How can I apply this formula to a column?

Answer (score 35):

Change `A1:A19240` to `A$1:A$19240`, i.e. apply:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A$1:A$19240,1,FALSE),"No Match")
```

This is called using [absolute references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9).

Comment: Hint/Tip: Edit the formula, put your cursor on the range and hit F4.  This will toggle absolute.  Keep toggling with F4 and you can anchor one side of the range.